# How do I reduce geometry in mesh?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, geometry

Over the course of modelling, my mesh has gained a bit too much geometry. If I use the Decimate modifier, it tells me I need to get rid of my Shape Keys, if I do that, the modifier messes up my UV seams. I've tried using Planar and selecting UV, but that just makes a mess of the UVs and the textures, even if I re-unwrap them.

[image]

Comment: Please Edit your title to express what you're looking for, as for the question, you can always model a low poly mesh, and bake the normals from high to low, actually, if you're modeling for a game, this is how it should be done. Yet for the shape keys, hmm... I'm not sure TBH if there's a work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide* will give a rather good result with your topology as it's mainly quads, then you'll have to make some corrections manually (<kbd>F</kbd> to make a quad from two triangles)

[image]

Comment: I had no idea that option was there. Thank you, I'll give it a go. :D

Comment: What's the best thing I can do to fix my textures/UVs? I've un-subdivided every object once, but the texturing, seams and UVs are broken? Thanks.

Comment: Yes sorry I guess you have to redo it